# Publishing a Self-Hosting Owin app in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, owin, azure-web-app-service, topshelf

I have an existing ASP.Net WebApi OWIN Self-hosting web application. The application is a simple console application and outputs a .exe file and some dlls.

Currently, the application can be hosted in two ways

1. By simply running the exe file. (Which will run as a console
   application)
2. As windows service using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) library.

The services can be consumed by accessing a configured URL and a port number.
Ex: http://www.demoapp.com:8080

Below code is the entry point of the application.

```
public class WebServer
{
    private IDisposable app;

    public void Start()
    {
        app = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: "http://demoapp.com:8080");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        app?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Requirement**

Now there is a requirement to host the application in Azure AppServices.
How can I achieve this without modifying existing code as much as possible?
Appreciated if you can provide a step by step instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the feature is not supported now.

You could vote up this [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/4606121-support-owin-self-hosting-in-azure-websites) to promote it to be achieved.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? Like, Wrapping console application within Asp.Net project?

Comment: In a Webjob, no. See Azure App Service sandbox limitations [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening). You have other options like Worker Role,Service Fabric, IaaS VMs , Docker containers in Azure App Service Linux, Azure Container Service or Azure Container Instance.